# How can I style a React Component from the Component container?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a component that I am routing to from App.jsx. I want the padding to be 10% on all sides on this one specific component. For the other components, I want the padding to be zero. I have tried styling from within the component, but it only adds whitespace to the sides. I want it to be grey on the sides, just like the footer.

I tried creating a className for the  element in my App.jsx and then editing the css stylesheet, but it didn't change anything.

In App.jsx:
    `<Route exact path="/" component={Home} className={styles.home} />`

In CSS Stylesheet:
    `.home { padding: 10%; }`

In Home component, padding is set to zero and the height is set to 100vh.

I have a content div that is wrapping the Switch statement with all of my Routes. Whatever I set the padding to with this, it applies to all of my components. I want only one component to have a separate padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conditional Styling**

If you want a certain component to have additional styles depending on the route (for example, only at the root route `"/"`), you can check the current route from within the component and change the CSS styles accordingly. You can do this by wrapping your component in the higher order component `withRouter` from React Router to get a `location` prop.

For example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    getClassName() {
        const { location } = this.props;

        if (location.pathname === "/") {
            return "home";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    render() {
        const className = this.getClassName();

        return (
            <div className={ className }>
                { /* whatever goes in here */ }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

**Gray Padding**

You also mention that you would like the padding to be gray. Padding cannot be colored, but what you can do is wrap the rendered content of your component in another HTML element that has a gray background color. Then place padding on the largest element.

Alternatively, you can just use a border if that works with your usecase.

Example:

```css
.container {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <strong>Content</strong>
    
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is still affecting it inside the Home component, which I do not want. I want to change the padding of the App component, but only for the home page

Comment: @llamasquared could you control passing the `className` in the router as in your example? The code I've posted just completes your code from the question. So the class would only be the `styles.home` class when rendering through the `Route` with the exact path `"/"`

Comment: What your code is doing is passing props to Home.jsx from App.jsx, and allowing App.jsx to style the Home component. However, the home component is set and I don't need to alter it. I am using the Content component from Antd to control the layout of my app in App.jsx. I need to change the padding of the content element, but only when the exact path is '/'

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<Route exact path="/">
  <Home className={styles.home}/>
</Route>
```

Comment: That didn't do anything to change the padding of the component